# What is the difference between invokeMethod and methodMissing?

Tags: groovy

In Groovy, what are the main differences between the `invokeMethod` and `methodMissing` methods, and are there clear guidelines when one should be used over the other?

Comment: Former is used to intercept **all** method/property access, later is used to intercept **failed** method/property access. Details [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+invokeMethod+and+getProperty).

Answer (score 4):

When to use what:
Always use methodMissing.

@FooBarUser. Thanks for pointing me to a page with wrong documentation, the page will be changed soon.

invokeMethod is not in general called for every method invocation, only in some situations. Which is also why methodMissing was added, to have a method with a clear role, unlike the sometimes fallback, sometimes frontend method invokeMethod

Comment: "invokeMethod is not in general called for every method invocation, only in some situations" --  which situations? From my understanding, according to the Groovy interception mechanism, it's when the method is missing and when there's no missingMethod() method. Which basically seems to be the same as missingMethod(); it just happens after.

Comment: I was not talking about the missingMethod case, I was targeting that invokeMethod is sometimes a frontend. That means for example if you call a method on GroovyObject from Java, then many use invokeMethod. That means it is called first - even if the real method exists. In Groovy you can have the same if you implement GroovyInterceptable. That forces to go through invokeMethod first from Groovy... In  Java you still have the choice. And because invokeMethod is such a legacy mess, I always tell people to use methodMissing instead if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a post [here](http://www.justinspradlin.com/programming/groovy-metaprogramming-creating-behavior-on-the-fly/)

> Before Groovy throws a MissingMethodException for calls that are made to methods not defined within a class, Groovy first routes the calls through an object's methodMissing() method. This gives programmers a chance to intercept calls to these non-existing methods and define an implementation for them.

And documentation [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+methodMissing+and+propertyMissing):

> Since 1.5, Groovy supports the concept of "methodMissing". This differs from invokeMethod in that it is only invoked in the case of failed method dispatch.
>
> 1) Since method/propertyMissing only occur in the case of failed dispatch, 
>       they are expensive to execute
>
> 2) Since method/propertyMissing aren't intercepting EVERY method call like 
>       invokeMethod they can be more efficient with a few meta-programming tricks

Answer (score 0):

invokeMethod() seems to be used quite a bit in the [decorator pattern Groovy doc](http://www.groovy-lang.org/single-page-documentation.html) when doing custom delegation. For example:

```
class TracingDecorator {
    private delegate
    TracingDecorator(delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate
    }
    def invokeMethod(String name, args) {
        println "Calling $name$args"
        def before = System.currentTimeMillis()
        def result = delegate.invokeMethod(name, args)
        println "Got $result in ${System.currentTimeMillis()-before} ms"
        result
    }
}
```

With that said, `def result = delegate.invokeMethod(name, args)` can be easily replaced with more modern Groovy idiom `def result = delegate."$name"(*args)`.